# Is it possible to reverse type-aligned traversals?

Tags: haskell, dependent-type

There's a lot of setup here. If you've ever seen a type-aligned sequence before, you can skim everything up to the line.

A type-aligned sequence is anything that looks vaguely like

```
data ConsList c x y where
  CNil :: ConsList c x x     
  Cons :: c x y -> ConsList c y z -> ConsList c x z
```

Given a class for Atkey-style indexed functors and applicative functors

```
class IxFunctor f where
  ixmap :: (a -> b) -> f x y a -> f x y b
class IxFunctor f => IxApply f where
  ixap :: f i j (a -> b) -> f j k a -> f i k b
class IxApply f => IxApplicative f where
  ixpure :: a -> f i i a
```

and a two-index McBride-style functor class:

```
type (f :: q -> r -> *) ~~> (g :: q -> r -> *) =
  forall (i :: q) (j :: r) . f i j -> g i j

class TFunctor t where
  tmap :: (c ~~> d) -> (t c ~~> t d)
```

it's possible to describe maps, folds and traversals that will work for type-aligned sequences:

```
class TFoldable t where
  tfoldMap :: Category d => (c ~~> d) -> t c ~~> d
  tfoldMap f = tfoldr (\cij djk -> f cij >>> djk) id

class (TFunctor t, TFoldable t) => TTraversable t where
  ttraverse :: IxApplicative f
            => (forall x y . c x y -> f x y (d x y))
            -> (t c p q -> f p q (t d p q))
```

Now it turns out that it's possible to define a version of `Data.Functor.Reverse` for type-aligned sequences. Specifically

```
newtype Reverse t c x y = Reverse {unReverse :: t (Dual c) y x}
```

where

```
newtype Dual c x y = Dual {getDual :: c y x}
```

When the type `t` is actually a type-aligned sequence, it's straightforward to give `Reverse t` the full complement of type-aligned sequence operations.

---

#### The actual question

What's *not* clear to me is whether `t` being `IxTraversable` is sufficient to implement `IxTraversable (Reverse t)`. Everything I've tried hits a brick wall. For standard `Traversable`s, this can be done using a `Backwards` applicative. There is an `IxBackwards` available, but it doesn't seem to help. For standard `Traversable`s, it's possible to dump the container contents into a list, then pull back in from the list. But that doesn't seem to be possible here, because there's no apparent way to record the types on the way out and ensure they'll match up on the way in. Have I missed something, or is this a no-go?

The barest start:

```
instance IxTraversable t => IxTraversable (Reverse t) where
  ttraverse f (Reverse xs) = Reverse `ixmap` _ xs
```

This gets me a hole of type

```
t (Dual c) q p -> f p q (t (Dual d) q p)
```

The obvious challenge is that we have `t _ q p`, but `f p q _`. So if there's a way to do this, we presumably need to somehow come up with an `f` that will flip things. As I said before, there's an `IxBackwards`

```
newtype IxBackwards f y x a = IxBackwards { ixforwards :: f x y a }
```

but I don't see how this helps.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your setup is sound, and `IxBackwards` *is* useful (in fact, critical) - the issue you have run into is the fact that both `Dual` and `Reverse` swap positions of type variables, whereas the first argument of `ttraverse` requires the positions of the quantified type variables (`x,y`) to 'agree' in a sense. You must simultaneously 'flip' these variables in the recursive call to `ttraverse` using *both* `Dual` and `IxBackwards`:

```
instance TTraversable t => TTraversable (Reverse t) where

  ttraverse f = 
    ixmap Reverse . ixforwards . 
    ttraverse (IxBackwards . ixmap Dual . f . getDual) . 
    unReverse
```

Writing the instances for `TFunctor` and `TFoldable` may give a hint as to how to find this implementation:

```
dualNat2 :: (c ~~> d) -> Dual c ~~> Dual d 
dualNat2 k (Dual x) = Dual $ k x 

instance TFunctor f => TFunctor (Reverse f) where 
  tmap f (Reverse q) = Reverse $ tmap (dualNat2 f) q 

instance TFoldable f => TFoldable (Reverse f) where 
  tfoldMap k (Reverse z) = getDual $ tfoldMap (dualNat2 k) z
```

You essentially do the same in the case of `TTraversable`, except now there are *two* indices to flip:

```
f                                      :: forall x y . c x y -> f x y (d x y)   
ixmap Dual . f . getDual               :: forall x y . Dual c y x -> f x y (Dual d y x)
IxBackwards . f                        :: forall x y . c x y -> IxBackwards f y x (d x y)
IxBackwards . ixmap Dual . f . getDual :: forall x y . Dual c y x -> IxBackwards f y x (Dual d y x)
```

and note that if you only flip one of the indices, the type of the function doesn't even match the type of the argument to `ttraverse`.

---

I'll try to give a step-by-step derivation using Typed Holes.

Begin with this skeleton, which I think is trivial to derive:

```
  ttraverse f = 
    ixmap Reverse .  
    ttraverse _trfun . 
    unReverse
```

This gives a type error:

```
Couldn't match type `q' with `p'
...
Expected type: Reverse t c p q -> f p q (Reverse t d p q)
Actual type: Reverse t c q p -> f p q (Reverse t d q p)
* In the expression: ixmap Reverse . ttraverse _trfun . unReverse
```

So add more holes until it compiles. My first instinct is to add another hole to the front (since the type error is for the whole expression, something has to be done to the whole expression to make it typecheck):

```
  ttraverse f = 
    _out . ixmap Reverse .  
    ttraverse _trfun . 
    unReverse
```

Now we get no type errors (ignoring 'ambiguous type' errors of the form `C x` where `C` is a class - there are erroneous) and the type reported is

```
 _out :: f0 q p (Reverse t c0 p q) -> f p q (Reverse t d p q)
```

where `f0, c0` are (currently) free type variables, which we use to our advantage! If we let `c0 ~ d` and `f0 ~ IxBackwards f` then this is precisely the type of `ixforwards` - so let's try it:

```
  ttraverse f = 
    ixforwards . ixmap Reverse .  
    ttraverse _trfun . 
    unReverse
```

and now we get a nice monomorphic inferred type:

```
 _trfun :: Dual c x y -> IxBackwards f x y (Dual d x y)
 * Relevant bindings include
     f :: forall (x :: r) (y :: r). c x y -> f x y (d x y)
```

Now I also assume it is obvious that `_trfun` should somehow use `f`, so let's try that. We notice that both the domain and range of `f` are not exactly that of `_trfun` so we place a hole on both sides:

```
  ttraverse f = 
    ixforwards . ixmap Reverse .  
    ttraverse (_out . f . _in) . 
    unReverse
```

and get:

```
_out :: f x0 y0 (d x0 y0) -> IxBackwards f x y (Dual d x y)
_in :: Dual c x y -> c x0 y0
```

where `x0, y0` are free variables. It is probably most obvious that with `x0 ~ y, y0 ~ x`, we have `_in = getDual`, so we try that, and get a new inferred type:

```
_out :: f y x (d y x) -> IxBackwards f x y (Dual d x y)
```

and now it is obvious to see that the type variables are 'flipped' in two different places; once by `IxBackwards` and once by `Dual`. The way to flip the first pair of indices is most obvious (probably):

```
  ttraverse f = 
    ixforwards . ixmap Reverse .  
    ttraverse (_out . IxBackwards . f . getDual) . 
    unReverse
```

and get:

```
_out :: IxBackwards f x y (d y x) -> IxBackwards f x y (Dual d x y)
```

Now we have something of the form `q A -> q B` with `IxFunctor q`, so setting `_out = ixmap _out` we get

```
_out :: d y x -> Dual d x y
```

and there is a trivial function of this type - namely `Dual` - which completes the definition:

```
  ttraverse f = 
    ixforwards . ixmap Reverse .  
    ttraverse (ixmap Dual . IxBackwards . f . getDual) . 
    unReverse
```

Note how some function compositions are flipped compared to the original version - I was pretending I didn't know the answer *a priori* and derived it in the 'most obvious' way, by filling in the things which are simplest first. The two definitions are equivalent (truly equivalent, since `Dual` and `IxBackwards` are both just `newtype`s).

Comment: Argh! I came really close to that answer in my efforts, but never quite got there. Do you think you could explain how you worked it out? Or how one *could* work it out?

Comment: I added a detailed derivation, which hopefully makes some sense. It still requires doing some typechecking in your head, but typed holes make this a bit easier.